# What unit are those GPS-coordinates?

Tags: python, gps, coordinates

I have a somewhat tricky problem: I want to draw the GPS-data from this dataset: https://zenodo.org/record/3267184

The problem is, that the coordinates (Longitude and Latitude) are somewhat cryptic, meaning I don't know which unit they are in and therefore I can't print them on a map. I have already tried a bunch of converters without any luck. BTW: The coordinates should be somewhere in Austria.

Here is some of the data: (second column is a timestamp)
Latitude:

```
[[2.8240872e+03 5.0000001e-02]
 [2.8240894e+03 1.0000000e-01]
 [2.8240894e+03 1.5000001e-01]
 [2.8240894e+03 2.0000000e-01]
 [2.8240894e+03 2.5000000e-01]
 [2.8240894e+03 3.0000001e-01]
 [2.8240894e+03 3.4999999e-01]
 [2.8240894e+03 4.0000001e-01]
 [2.8240894e+03 4.4999999e-01]]
```

Longitude:

```
[[9.2659589e+02 5.0000001e-02]
 [9.2659406e+02 1.0000000e-01]
 [9.2659406e+02 1.5000001e-01]
 [9.2659406e+02 2.0000000e-01]
 [9.2659412e+02 2.5000000e-01]
 [9.2659418e+02 3.0000001e-01]
 [9.2659418e+02 3.4999999e-01]
 [9.2659418e+02 4.0000001e-01]
 [9.2659418e+02 4.4999999e-01]]
```

Is anybody able to tell me how I convert those values into coordinates that are usable, ideally into WDS84? I am using Python right now for my tool.

Here is the code I got so far:

```
import h5py
with h5py.File('../../_datasets/20181214_Driver3_Trip2.hdf', 'r') as f:
    lat = f['Math/Latitude_Vehicle']
    long = f['Math/Longitude_Vehicle']
```

Comment: What exactly do you find cryptic about those numbers?

Comment: i can't draw them on a map. if i do that, the markers are all the way up on the northpole. I think they are out of the range of the matplotlib-drawing-function. Do you know which format they are in @mkrieger1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. It was already in the correct unit - just needed to divide the values by 60 (minutes) and it worked :)

Thanks everyone who tried to help me :)